# Not getting all events with session info

Tags: firebase, google-analytics, google-bigquery

Does anybody know how to be sure that all the events get the 'ga_session_number' and 'ga_session_id' parameters with firebase?

Right now I'm getting only a 3% of the total events with those parameters and it should be on every event. Last sdk version is loaded on the app.

Thanks in advance for the help

The query I'm making is the following:

```
SELECT 
    user_pseudo_id, event.value.int_value session,
    MIN(event_previous_timestamp), MAX(event_previous_timestamp), 
    MAX(event_timestamp) - MIN(event_timestamp), 
    COUNT(*) 
FROM 
    `table`, 
    UNNEST(event_params) AS event
WHERE 
    event.key = 'ga_session_number'
GROUP BY 
    1, 2
ORDER BY 
    2
```

The total event rows on the table are more than 3 million, and getting only 100k with the query.

UPDATE:
Firebase support team has updated the analitycs SDK solving this issue.

Comment: Hi Oscar welcome to SO, Can you please share how you are fetching your data from BigQuery and provide an example of missing records from your output. Also, I suggest doing some research about ga_session topics as there are quite a few questions on this subject which might help you

Comment: can you please add the query to your question following SO format guide lines

Comment: @TamirKlein I edited the first question adding the query I made. Thanks for your help and support!